# Sequelize Many to Many not associated problem

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I work on an application where users can design their own custom forms. I'm using Sequelize and Postgress.

It has an online form where users can create their custom forms. I have two entities where it should show forms for **Event** and **Event Type**.

- The Event can be of different Event Type.
- Each Event Type has its form created through form builder.
- Event should show different form per chosen Event Type.
- Saving the Event should save all fields including those of that event Type, and those values should be associated to event now.

I have used the following post to model Form Builder:

```
Event
-------
  id
  name
  typeId (FK to eventType.id)

Event Type
-----
  id (PK)
  name

Form_elements
-------------
  id (PK)
  eventType_id (FK to eventType.id)
  element_type_id (FK to element_types.id)

Element_types
-------------
  id (PK)
  name

Element_list_values
-------------------
  id (PK)
  element_id (FK to form_elements.id)
  event_id (FK to event.id)
  value
```

When user is on Add or Edit Form how would a select query to generate table from the form fields and the field_values from this schema?

I have tried the following code:

```
formField.findAll({
        where: {
            eventTypeId: typeId,
        },
        include: [{
            model: formFieldType,
        },
        {
            model: formFieldValue,
            as: 'FormFieldValues',
        }],
    });
```

But I keep getting :

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: formFieldValue is not associated to formField!

Here are my model associations:

```
EventType.hasMany(FormField);
FormField.belongsTo(EventType);
FieldType.hasMany(FormField, { foreignKey: 'typeId', as: 'type' });
FormField.belongsTo(FieldType, { foreignKey: 'typeId' });

// field value
Event.belongsToMany(FormField, { through: 'formFieldValues', foreignKey: 'event_id' });
FormField.belongsToMany(Event, { through: 'formFieldValues', foreignKey: 'field_id' });
```

Comment: You don't have an explicit association between `FormField` and `formFieldValues`

Comment: @Antoly Hmm How could I do that :)

Comment: Like this `FormField.hasMany(FormFieldValues, { foreignKey: 'field_id' })`

Comment: If you wish to get Event instances that are linked to FormField then you should include `Event` and not `FormFieldValues`